# How to forecast time series for many products, including a seasonality factor in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608121/how-to-forecast-time-series-including-a-seasonality-factor-in-r) with one product to forecast, lets say I have 5 products to forecast as in the following data:

```
 units_vector <- c(89496264,81820040,80960072,109164545,96226255,96270421,95694992,117509717,105134778,0)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table('time' = rep(c(1:10),3),
                 'units'= c(units_vector,units_vector+runif(n = 10, max = 1000000),units_vector+runif(n = 10, max = 1000000)),
                 'product' = c(rep("A", 10),rep("B", 10),rep("C", 10))
)
```

I would like to forecast the `units` for `time = 10` for all `product`s.

I can see that at `time = 4*k`, where `k = 1,2,...` there is a big increase of units, and I would like to include that as a seasonality factor.

How could I do that in `R` ? Maybe with `prophet` ? Any other `library` or way will also do.

Comment: That's exactly the same question

Comment: @AlainD how is it exactly the same ? in the previous question I had one product and now I have 5 for which I want a separate forecast in one go

Answer (score 0):

You do the same: fit the model `y = a*season + b` with `b = p(product)` depending on the product and `a`equal for all products (if you assume the seasonality is the same for all products).